# Django Queryset filter related field isnull lookup last object, Book (Loan - Return)

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'll show an example of a model, and discuss the issue here. Because it's hard to describe with a question.

```
# models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=100)

class Loan(models.Model):
    book = ForeignKey(Book)

class Return(models.Model):
    loan = ForeignKey(Loan)
```

> Book is available === Book is not loaned or Last loan has return the book

```
# Available:
Book.objects.filter(
            Q(loan__isnull=True)|           # Book has never been borrowed           
            Q(loan__return__isnull=False)   # Book has been borrowed but returned
).distinct()
```

The above filter is partially correct.

The only problem happens when the `Book` has been returned and re-loaned again.

After the book being loaned, it should not be available, but it will return as `available` with the above queryset, because the `loan__return__isnull=False` is still exists for that particular book.

I couldn't figure out any better approach in such query. How could we make such simple query to work?

---

### Possible Solution

The solution that I could think of is very ugly. It involves multiple separate queries. But roughly the step involves as follow:

1. querying **last** `Loan` group by the `Book`. (Book has been borrowed)
2. filter `Loan` which `Return` is null. (Book is not yet return)
3. Query `Book`, matching all of those `Loan` satisfying condition 2.
4. Query `Book`, which `Loan` is null. (Book never been borrowed)

Note (3 & 4 is combined together as one Query)

Comment: I think you solution is fine with your model setup, have you tried that?

Comment: @ShangWang I haven't tried to code the above solution yet, because I am not sure how to make those query efficient. Instead, I tried to solve those problem with different approach, like using [Count of Loan and Return](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34609725/764592) as the temporary **good enough** solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Book.objects.filter(
        Q(loan__isnull=True) # Book has never been borrowed 
        | ( Q(loan__return__isnull=True) & Q(loan__isnull=False)) ) # Book has been borrowed but not returned
        | Q(loan__return__isnull=False) # Book has been borrowed but returned
).distinct()
```

Comment: This does not resolve the issue: After the Book has been returned and re-loaned again, the book is still returned as available.

Answer (score 1):

### Different Approach to this Problem.

> It solve my problem, but I could not prove that its correctness.

In this approach, I will use `Count` of both `Loan` and `Return`.

- If the `Count(Loan)==Count(Return)`, then `Book` is available
- else `Book` is not available

#### Sample Code

```
# Available Books
Book.objects.annotate(
    loan_count=Count('loan'),
    return_count=Count('loan__return')
).filter(Q(issue_count=F('return_count')))

# Unavailable Books
Book.objects.annotate(
    loan_count=Count('loan'),
    return_count=Count('loan__return')
).exclude(Q(issue_count=F('return_count')))
```